# Longest sequence of even numbers in python without libraries

Tags: python, list

I need to find a longest sequence of 5's in a list `user_scores = [1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5]` without using any libraries or built in functions (like `max`)

My solution is

```
key = 5
max_sequence = 0
current_sequence = 0
new_sequence = 0
for score in user_scores:
    if score == key:
        current_sequence += 1
        current_sequence = max_sequence
    elif score != key:
        current_sequence = 0
else:
    print(max_sequence)
```

Obviously it doesn't work at all. Trying my best to learn algorithms so i would appreciate an explanation with a code.

Comment: `current_sequence = max_sequence` is backwards, and you'd need to do this assignment only if the value is greater than the current `max_sequence` (otherwise, you're just measuring the last sequence of 5's).

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for reply. I will definitely be looking more in this problem of mine.

Comment: How does "longest sequence of even numbers" relate to "longest sequence of 5's"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the explanation in comment will make it clear, if not please ask I'll make  a more detailed answer :)

```py
user_scores = [1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5]
key = 5
max_sequence = 0
current_sequence = 0
for score in user_scores:
    if score == key:
        #If it's the right key then you found another one in the sequence 
        current_sequence += 1
    else:
        #Otherwise you'r not in a sequence so current_sequence size is empty 
        current_sequence = 0

    if current_sequence > max_sequence:
        #If the current sequence size is bigger than the max then it's the new max
        max_sequence = current_sequence

print(max_sequence)
```

Comment: I appreciate the comments you inserted. Going to save those for future references. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. If you reach to different num reset long_seq.
2. If updating long_seq save this update in max_seq (if larger than previous longest sequense).

like below:

```
user_scores = [1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5]

def find_long_seq(arr, key):
    long_seq = 0
    max_seq = 0
    for num in arr:
        if num == key:
            long_seq += 1
            if long_seq > max_seq:
                max_seq = long_seq
        elif num != key:
            long_seq = 0

    return max_seq
    
print(find_long_seq(user_scores, 5))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: I started with the same logic, but it didn't work. Guess my syntax was bad. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5]

MAX, counter = 0, 0
for i in l:
    if i != 5:
        if counter > MAX:
            MAX = counter
        counter = 0  # reset
    else:
        counter += 1 # increment if 5 is matched

# final fix
if counter > MAX:
    MAX = counter

print(MAX)
```

If lists are allowed:

```
l = [1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1, 5]

a = []
for i in l:
    if i != 5:
        a.append(0)
    else:
        a[-1] += 1

MAX = 0
for i in a:
    if i > MAX:
        MAX = i
print(MAX)
```